# how to include a template to a category of a specific taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i'm trying to make a pluging that show a custom category list and i'm using

```
function page_template( $template )
{
    if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'gallery' ) {
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/custom-page-template.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'page_template' );
and is working good, now i get the url from each category using 
<?php 
     $value = term_exists( 'category', 'taxonomy' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given 
        if(isset($value)){?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 'category', taxonomy ) ?>" > Blepharoplasty</a>
<?php } ?>
```

and too working working good.
now i need know how add a new template when i do click in the url that obtain with the get_term_link().

Thanks

Comment: What exactly so you mean "how to add a new template"? You have specified the template you are using in your function, so do you not already have a template to use? If you are running into a specific problem, then please edit your question to let us know exactly what the problem is so that we can help. If you are looking for information on how to develop a brand new template, then that is off topic for Stack Overflow, but there are lots of online tutorials etc with instructions.

Comment: i have a custom page template  that show the list of terms and i show it with a shortcode, then i need that when i do click in the link of each term, load a new  and diferent page template. i know that i need use the taxomomy and the category asociated, but i don't know how. i guess that should be any like this  <?php function page_template( $template )
{ if ( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'gallery' ){$template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/custom-page-template.php'; }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'page_template' );?> but i dont know how manage. thanks!